# Is it possible to follow a question and get notified whenever a new answer is added?

Tags: feature-request

As a beginner LaTeX user, many questions/answers are encyclopedic to me and expand my knowledge and understanding. However, favoriting tons of questions doesn't help that much to keep the information fresh in my mind.

So, is there a possibility in the future to make users able to follow reputable questions and get notified in case of every new answer?

Comment: Well, this is quite similar to this question (but's not a duplicate, in my point of view: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6807/wouldnt-it-be-nice-if-we-can-also-bookmark-the-answer)

Comment: Good questions are answered quickly. It is very rare, that a question gets a helpful answer a year later. Almost all *late answers* on site are not answers to the question.

Comment: @Johannes_B, there is a kind of questions where it doesn't age and every new answer can be informative.  For example, questions about software solutions for conversion between beamer and powerpoint, defining code for particular tables/figures output, etc. Even though they are answered, every new answer expands the knowledge in one way or another at least for beginners.

Comment: @Johannes_B Having 29 revival badges and 10 necromancer badges, I can't really agree to that ;-) Sometimes questions are missed when they're first posted. (Maybe there was a high volume of posts that quickly pushed them off the first page.) Sometimes I stumble on an interesting question when looking through the unanswered list that wasn't easy to solve when it was first posted, but new features make it easier to address now.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Ok, fair point. You are right. I do have one or two of each, but it was mostly to get a few untouched question (whyever they are untouched) off the unanswered list. Also, a few answers from the beginning are one-liners and they could need some attention. But adding an alternative answer that does the same the same way won't stand against an accepted and upvoted 80 times answer. It would be bettr to edit them in order to make the Q/A-pair as a whole better.

Comment: @Johannes_B Sorry I misunderstood. I thought by late answers you meant late answers to long-standing unanswered questions. You're right, there are a lot of poor additional answers that don't add anything, but I think it's useful to be able to follow a question (although I thought the star under the up/down vote buttons allows that) especially if the only answer involves internal hacks.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Favouriting a question puts it in your favourite list. If you get a note if there is some new content: I have absolutely no idea.

Comment: @Johannes_B I just found [How do favorite questions work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work) which seems to answer this question.

Comment: This is a duplicate, of a question that is on Meta Stack Exchange, somewhere.
If I  rightly from that post: very very early in Stack Overflow history, Favorite used to do this -- give you notifications like as if it was your question. But then that broken, and was never fixed, and now bring it back would break a bunch of peoples work-flows. I believe there is a Feature request to add something like that as a new feature floating around on Meta Stack Exchange still. I'ld love it. If I bounty a question I probably care more than the OP.

Answer (score 7):

If you favorite a question that has your favorite answer, you'll get a ping at the user profile page or whatever that is called by SO -- probably kernel panic room or something tastes like nerdburger like that --

Here I have 4 changes happened to stuff that I have favorited before.

[image]

Comment: That looks interesting and is new to me. However, I am a bit greedy and would like to find these notifications in my inbox at the top bar instead of frequently checking this page in my profile. Nonetheless, you helped me much by explaining to me that feature.

Comment: The one annoying thing about these notifications is however that they also occur, when nothing new happened at the question but it was only bumped to the front page by the bot.

Comment: @samcarter Those are bumped if there are no answers though ...